# Wicked_pdf and utf8 symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, utf-8, wicked-pdf

In my generated pdf I get this

```
0,00 â‚¬
```

instead of

```
0,00 €
```

**Application.html.erb**

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%=number_to_currency item.total%>
```

Answer (score 25):

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render template: 'invoices/show' }
  format.pdf  do
    render pdf: 'invoices/show',
           template: 'invoices/show', 
           formats: :HTML, 
           encoding: 'utf8'
  end
end
```

Comment: You can also put same setting `encoding: 'utf8'` into your initializers\wicked_pdf config file

Answer (score 1):

Still i can see the special characters in the PDF. Below is my code

```
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(page_html,:page_size => "A3") 

  send_data(pdf, 
    :filename => "my_pdf_name.pdf", 
    :formats => 'HTML', 
    :encoding => 'utf8',
    :disposition => 'attachment') 
  end
```

Comment: I use this format.pdf do
        render  pdf: "invoice",
                layout: 'layouts/metronic/blank.pdf',
                template: 'invoices/show',
                formats: :html,
                encoding: 'utf8'
      end

Comment: Check for valid HTML doctype

Comment: Yes, I am using the format as HTML and utf8 as encoding. Can you just tell, what's wrong with the above code snippet

Answer (score 0):

**config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb**

```
  WickedPdf.config = {
    encoding: 'utf8'
  }
```